# Weed Smoking in This is the End

Tags: realism, props, this-is-the-end

[*This is the End* (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1245492/) features scenes where Seth Rogen smokes weed. It's no secret that Seth Rogen likes to smoke weed, and from [this](https://www.kpopstarz.com/articles/30956/20130611/seth-rogen-weed-the-end-craig-robinson.htm) link, it would seem they often did it off camera.

On camera; is he really smoking weed, or is it a prop the production team gave him?

I guess you would have to look at what the law says during that time (2013). I can only assume at the time it was illegal and it was, in fact, a prop.

Comment: Keep in mind, its still illegal no matter what state you are in according to federal law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that there are about a hundred people on set who

- don't want to get arrested and/or
- don't like the smell and/or
- other reasons - relating to health, safety, public interest, being sued...

Props are pretty handy at breaking up herbal cigarettes and re-rolling them into Rizlas, including putting an authentic torn-off roach in the end.

Herbal cigarettes are at once the bane and the saviour of the film industry. It's not so much that they're been proven 'safe' more that they haven't been proven 'dangerous' and there is no legislation against smoking them indoors, outdoors, anywhere.

Just because they taste and smell like the bonfire at the far end of the park is no excuse if you're making 'period drama' or 'bad boys doing drugs' and artistically, people in that situation 'smoke'.

Comment: Also, if they had to reshoot the scene 10-20 times from different angles, actual marijuana might have gotten Seth a lot more stoned than he would be comfortable with. (There might also be health & safety concerns.)

Comment: That's actually a very valid point I hadn't considered - one joint 'good' 17 joints 'bad' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The film was shot entirely in New Orleans, Louisiana, where recreational use wasn't decriminalized until 2015.  Therefore, considering it was a major Hollywood production, it's logical to believe that recreational drug use was not allowed during filming.

I'm sure that interview was overblown, as it was part of the press junket for the movie.  Actors have been known to lie quite frequently during these marketing-based interviews.  Let's face it; if you're in a movie where the target audience is the drug culture, you're not going to say, "Oh, we never smoked the stuff once".  It's part of the build-up; creating the legend.  Rogen, who is from Canada, has also been quoted as saying he doesn't smoke much on US soil because law enforcement is so strict about it.